# Is it possible to echo characters directly to network?

Tags: networking, hex

Even when this is a network problem, I would say this is rather a Unix/Linux experienced users question.

I am trying to **manually send a network** magic packet by using **echo and redirectors** (file descriptors).
This is an **example** of the data that must be sent via network broadcast (to 255.255.255.255) to wake computer with **MAC 00:17:31:3F:D3:A9** (FFFFFFFFFFFF followed by 16 times the MAC without colons):

```
ffffffffffff0017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a9
```

I have sent a wake on LAN magic packet from my usual programs ([IH WOL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ih-wol/), or `wakeonlan` tool for Linux) that worked fine, and I **captured** the network traffic with WireShark:

[image: Magic Packet working]

Note the highlighted green area: the magic packet is **correctly** sent as Hex.

And now it is time for the **redirectors echo** method.
I am echoing the magic packet to broadcast IP address, UDP protocol, port number 4000:

```
exec 6<>/dev/udp/255.255.255.255/4000
echo "ffffffffffff0017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a90017313fd3a9" >&6
```

**No results** (remote computer does not wake up). The WireShark's capture is this time slightly **different**:

[image: Magic Packet not working]

As can be seen, the magic packet is now on the right side (!), the supposed `binary area` of the info. On the left area, each `F` appears as `66` (its ASCII code, I assume), each `0` as `30`... etc.
And, by the way, the data is not detected as "MagicPacket" by WireShark.

What is the **correct way to send** my data via shell directly to the NIC?

P.S: maybe this question must be transferred to ServerFault? I think it is rather like some sort of hex to ascii or binary conversion issue.

Answer (score 4):

Really easy:

- Add the **hex specification "\x"** each two characters.
- Use `echo -e` for hex to be **interpreted**. Also you can use `printf` because `echo` does different things in different shells.

Using your same example data:

```
echo -e "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9\x00\x17\x31\x3f\xd3\xa9" >&6
```

This time your computer should wake up.

- **NOTE**: not all the shells do **support this feature**. In fact, only a few do. Refer to [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217469/what-are-the-linux-shells-that-allow-network-traffic-management-sending-receivi) to know which one do. For me, **Cygwin** latest version (June 2015) for Windows running `Bash 4.3.39(2)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)` works perfect.
- **NOTE-2**: Sadly, Ubuntu (v14.04) and Kali (v1.1.0) seem **not to support** it as for today, as explained in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217613/bash-permission-denied-when-trying-to-echo-data-directly-to-nic). It has probably been disabled on Bash, due to problems with networking compatibility.
- **NOTE-3**: Well, I must admit that people (see above threads) reporting that `/dev/protocol/host/port` is not a proper method are completely right. For example, the Hex code `\x0a` acts as some control code for network datagrams, splitting the packet. So you can not use MAC address like `0a:11:22:33:44:55` with this method. Time to switch to `netcat` or [`socat`](https://serverfault.com/a/246479/407820).

Comment: Does this work? Impressive. I would suggest using `printf` rather than `echo` because `echo` does different things in different shells - its behavior differs even between `ksh` and `bash` which are the two which I would suppose this might work in. `printf` is fairly reliable, however. Anyway, could please elaborate on opening `>&6` in the first place? Where does it go? My bad - `/dev/udp/...`. Good q/a. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, this work, @mikeserv. The bad news: recent Bash versions seem to have disabled it (I still can use it via CygWin's Bash). The good news: it can be easily replaced by `netcat` or `socat`. I have opened this thread that expands info about this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217469/what-are-the-linux-shells-that-allow-network-traffic-management-sending-receivi . I think all your questions will be answered there, even the `>&6` (in the case of just sending data there is no need to use it, in fact; it is just por readability purposes).

Comment: @mikeserv , tested your `printf`. It works OK, thanks you.

Comment: And more bad news, @mikeserv : even when Bash would accept them, file redirectors are not a valid solution (see NOTE-3).

Comment: Your last note isn't true. And anyway, I would never do such a thing with `bash` - `bash` is the worst shell there is.

Comment: @mikeserv , I have performed the test with a MAC including "0a" string, and the package becomes split, disabling the Wake on LAN capability. Maybe you can add some info explaining why NOTE-3 is not true?

Comment: That's because you mix encodings. If you want to encode all data as hex then do. `0a` in hex is x30x61

Comment: And by the way, actually mixing the encodings is much easier w/ `printf` because you can use format strings w/ multiple args. Try `printf "%s:\t%b\n" '\x30\x61' '\x30\x61'`

Comment: @mikeserv, I am not sure to understand. I fear there could be some ambiguity. How would then I translate the problematic example MAC to hex: `0a:11:22:33:44:55` ? And this other MAC: `0a:30:61:0a:30:61` ?