# netcat broadcast understanding

Tags: networking, netcat

I'm using macOS with gnu netcat. I want to understand how can I broadcast message using netcat.

I have a `netcat` listening on 4555

`netcat -l -p 4555 192.168.0.101`

but as I attempt to send a broadcast message

`netcat 192.168.0.255 4555` but I keep getting following err

`Error: Couldn't create connection (err=-5): Permission denied`

I'm getting the following error

`Error: Couldn't create connection (err=-5): Permission denied`

The [following post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217683/netcat-ignoring-not-sending-network-data-to-broadcast-addresses) says it is possible to do so using `netcat-traditional` but I'm running GNU netcat does that matter over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to get to the points:

- TCP doesn't work with broadcast.

  You simply can't use TCP to connect to a broadcast IP address. *netcat* uses TCP by default unless told to use UDP, and such attempt gets an error.
- UDP broadcast requires to set a flag but GNU netcat doesn't handle it.

  That's how is working the BSD socket API and its extensions through `setsockopt(2)`. To be able to send a packet to a broadcast IPv4 address (for protocols that support broadcast), `SO_BROADCAST` is mandatory. Else this will trigger an error. The [GNU netcat sources](https://sourceforge.net/p/netcat/code/HEAD/tree/) don't include anywhere the string `SO_BROADCAST`.

So, there is no possibility for GNU netcat to send a broadcast. You have to switch to an other tool. Either an other variant of *netcat* (there are multiple around) or use instead [`socat`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/socat) which has more features. Here's a link about [using `socat` with (multicast and) broadcast](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-multicast.html). It does handle having two sides with a socket, like (apparently) GNU netcat's tunnel mode.